# How to Display Tabs after form is saved in YII Framework

Tags: yii

I want to display tabs after the header form is saved, Please see attached image,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter in to redirect URL after save method. Then in your view, add code like;

```
$activeTab= null;
if(isset($_GET['tab'])){
   $activeTab = $_GET['tab'];
}
```

and in your tabs class control the value of the $activeTab variable

```
if($activeTab == 'Reflists'){
   echo "<li class = "blabla active">Reflist</li>";
}
else {
   echo "<li class = "blabla">Reflist</li>";
}
```

this is example of the tab code.

Answer (score 0):

Here some working example

from Controller.

```
  $activeTab = 0; 
if(isset($_POST['WorPerformance']))
        {
                     $activeTab = 2; //set the selected tabs here
            $worperfm->attributes=$_POST['WorPerformance'];
            if($worperfm->save()){
                           $msg2 = CHtml::link('View Details',array('view','id'=>$worperfm->WOR_ID));
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','You data have been saved successfully. '.$msg2);
                    }
        }
$this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
                        'endorsp'=>$endorsp, //variable tabs 0
                        'enddetail'=>$enddetail, //variable tabs 1
                        'worperfm'=>$worperfm, //variable tabs 2
                        'activeTab'=>$activeTab,//pass the variable here
        ));
```

from View :

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs',array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        'PF Log Details'=>array('id'=>'endetails-id','content'=>$this->renderPartial(
                                        '/enddetail/_formpf',
                                        array('model'=>$model),TRUE
                                        )),
       'Endorsement Species'=>array('id'=>'endorsespecies-id','content'=>$this->renderPartial(
                                        '/endorspecies/_formClone2',
                                        array('model'=>$model),TRUE
                                        )),
       'Work Performance'=>array('id'=>'worperform-id','content'=>$this->renderPartial(
                                        '/worPerformance/_formpf',array('worPerformance'=>$worperfm 
                                                                                    ),TRUE)),

    ),
    'options'=>array(
        'collapsible'=>true,
        'selected'=>$activeTab,//get from controller variable 'activeTab'=>$activeTab
    ),
    'id'=>'MyTab-Menu',
));
?>
```